# Is "all HTML elements are a single word" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context, grammatical-number

> [This prevents conflicts with existing and future HTML elements, since *all HTML elements are a single word*.](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/multi-word-component-names.html#rule-details) (from "vue/multi-word-component-names")

Is "all HTML elements are a single word" grammatically correct?

Or should it be "all HTML elements are single words"?

Comment: I'd prefer ***Every** HTML element **is a single word.*** Or ***each** element* - but to my mind ***every*** is more "emphatic" here, which works better in the exact context as cited.

Comment: Note that although *Every Cretan is a liar,* and *All Cretans are liars* are both fine, *Each Cretan is a liar* is a bit odd (but *Each Cretan can decide for himself whether to lie or not* is fine). Crucially, though, ***All Cretans are a liar*** is completely unacceptable in ***any*** context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Since [_"Dolphins are a kind of whale" is perfectly correct grammar_](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/dolphins-are-a-kind-of-whale.3073800/post-15540327), I guess _"all HTML elements are a single word"_ is also grammatically correct?

Comment: No, you can't extrapolate from dolphins to HTML like that. *Dolphins* there means *dolphins collectively* - it can be replaced by ***The dolphin** is a kind of whale* (a "generic" statement about dolphins). But you can't say ***The HTML element** is a single word* as a generic assertion about HTML elements (though in some contexts you could say that about *a single specific instance of an HTML element*).

Comment: btw - I asked ChatGPT whether your assertion was true. It said: ***No, a dolphin is not a kind of whale**, although they are both members of the same taxonomic order, Cetacea, which also includes porpoises. Whales and dolphins are both marine mammals that have adapted to life in the water, but there are several differences between them.*

Comment: ...but it gave several more paragraphs after that, so I asked : ***please answer in a single sentence - is a dolphin a kind of whale?*** Quick as a flash, it came back with ***No, a dolphin is not a kind of whale.***

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was citing that sentence from a forum, you can click it to see the source XD.

Comment: Well, presumably you thought there was something "odd" about that sentence, or you wouldn't have asked about it here. I don't really care about a possible difference between "grammatically **in**correct" and "constructions which I don't like". The text you cited looks awful to me - as I said in my first comment, I'd prefer ***Every*** or ***Each*** (+singular) rather than ***All*** (+plural). Your cited text is perfectly comprehensible, but I advise you not to copy it, or assume you can use it as a guide to what is or isn't grammatically correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... all HTML elements are a single word

As written, this is at least technically incorrect, although most fluent speakers would correctly understand the intended meaning, and might not even notice the error.

More correct forms with the intended meaning, or a very similar meaning would include:

> - Every HTML element is a single word.
> - Each HTML element is a single word.
> - All HTML elements are single words
> - All HTML elements consist of  a single word.
> - All HTML elements consist of  a single token.
> - All HTML elements are identified by  a single token.
> - Every HTML element is identified by  a single token.

Other similar forms are also possible. Each of the above is grammatically valid, although some of them are not quite correct in meaning, as many HTML elements are not actually words, and most consist of more than the identifying token.